# A combinatorial problem on hypergraph edges

Tags: combinatorics

From an application the following problem arises:

Given a finite set $K$, consisting of "pairs" of objects (two "kinds" of a certain finite set $E$),

$T$, a family of subsets of $E$.

$B$, a family of subsets of $T$, such that the union of $B$ has either no elements of $E$ of a certain "kind" or both "kinds" of  a certain element.

Is there any particular structure for $B$ ? Or an efficient way to enumerate it?

Example:

given:
$$E= \{C,D,F\}$$
$$\implies K= \{C^+,C^-,D^+,D^-,F^+,F^-\}$$
given:
$$T: t_1=\{C^+\} ,t_2=\{D^+\}, t_3=\{C^-\}, t_4=\{D^-,C^+\}, t_5=\{F^-,C^+\}$$

$$ \implies B= \{t_1,t_3\}, \{t_2,t_4,t_3\} , \{t_1,t_2,t_4,t_3\}$$

I'm currently considering an hypergraph representation, but I cannot get my head around how to use it to obtain a productive way to think about $B$ or efficiently enumerate it.

Another hypergraph representation is produced by "splitting" the edges which involve elements of the two "kinds", artifically adding nodes $V$ representing this to T:

$$T' : t'_1=\{C^+\} , t'_2=\{D^+\} , t'_3=\{C^+\} , t'_4=\{v_1^-,D^-\} , t'_5=\{v_1^+,C^+\} , t'_6=\{F^-,v_2^-\} $$
$$t'_7=\{C^+,v_2^+\} $$
$$\implies B' =  \{t'_1,t'_3\} , \{t'_2,t'_4,t'_5,t'_3\} , \{t'_1,t'_2,t'_4,t'_5,t'_3\} $$

Comment: Why not $\{t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4\}$? It has the same union as $\{t_2,t_3,t_4\}$.

Comment: Right. Edited. Thanks!